# Why does cURL return an empty string?

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

I'm having a problem with PHP's cURL returning an empty string with some URL's.  I'm trying to  parse the OG metadata of different webpages and it works with all websites I've tried except for NYTimes.  Here is my code so far.

```
print_r(get_og_metadata('http://somewebsite.com'));


public function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    // the url to fetch
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // return result as a string rather than direct output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // set max time of cURL execution
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

public function get_og_metadata($url)
{
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $data = $this->_get_data($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';

    $metadatas = $xpath->query($query);
    $result = array();
    foreach($metadatas as $metadata)
    {
        $property = $metadata->getAttribute('property');
        $content = $metadata->getAttribute('content');
        $result[$property] = $content;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: function called `get_data` but you call `_get_data` ?

Comment: whoops! that was just a mistake when copying the code here. good catch though!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is that a site like the New York times has protection against such behavior.
Most likely this is based on the user agent, which you can fake as so:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
```

This is the most common agent btw.

Comment: Setting the user agent didn't work but setting auto_referrer to TRUE actually did. Your answer did help me rethink what could have been causing the problem though!

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

Answer (score 36):

### These 5 lines did the magic for me.

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` save me. Thanks

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` did the trick

Answer (score 12):

(That other answer is me also)

This is what did it for me. It was looking for SSL verificaiton, which I happened to not need in this specific case.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Comment: This helped me in going to an SSL API from a dev (non-SSL) environment. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as well...

i tried try/catch option to try to catch any errors, but curl response was just blank... no errors. Soon as i added this, i got response from HTTPS server

Comment: This one did that for me!

Answer (score 4):

This is what did it for me. It was looking for SSL verificaiton, which I happened to not need in this specific case.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```