# PHP curl won't return proper results

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, bots

I'm currently doing something like a search-bot, some kind of web crawler. I found out that curl has some kind of multi-url-get-content. Here is my code:

```
protected function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

    // array of curl handles
    $curly = array();
    // data to be returned
    $result = array();

    // multi handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    // loop through $data and create curl handles
    // then add them to the multi-handle
    foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

        $curly[$id] = curl_init();

        $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
    }

    // execute the handles
    $running = null;
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running > 0);
    //} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    // get content and remove handles
    foreach ($curly as $id => $c) {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }

    // all done
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return $result;
}
```

It worked when passing a single array with one link. Then it returns an array containing onr big String (the html content).
However, when calling it a second time with a significant bigger array (~30 links), it returns me an array with the same size full of empty strings, as if the server just didn't want to answer all these requests. Is there a problem with my code?

Thanks for your help

Erik Brendel

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found it. Just a bit recherche: [Why does cURL return an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679886/why-does-curl-return-an-empty-string)

Seems like these 5 lines actually did the magic

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```